# Why can't I import classes and enums from namespace?

Tags: typescript, pg-promise

I use Typescript with pg-promise and I don't quite understand why I can't import the various classes and enums as I usually do. Usually when I use a library, I import a type, use it and it works just fine. In the code below, I'm trying to create a "mode" to be used in my transactions, so I import `TransactionMode` and `isolationLevel` but they are actually undefined at run time (no errors during design time and compile time). `esModuleInterop` is `true` in my `tsconfig.json`.

```js
import pgPromise, { isolationLevel, TransactionMode } from "pg-promise";

const pgp = pgPromise();

// Doing this works, but I don't understand why it's necessary.
// const { TransactionMode, isolationLevel } = pgp.txMode;

// Here the imported TransactionMode and isolationLevel are undefined
const mode = new TransactionMode({ tiLevel: isolationLevel.serializable });

(...)
```

to be used in my code, instead having to pull the name

Comment: You got your answer, plus see the update there. Please accept, if this concludes the issue.

Comment: @vitaly-t I didn't get my answer, plus the answer you gave was already spelled out in my question. I was asking "why" I had to import `isolationLevel` and `TransactionMode` from a namespace instead of using the standard `import` mechanism and then using the imported items. You said it's because your lib is written in JS, but I've used a lot of JS libs with TS types declarations and I can just use the imported objects. Not saying you did it wrong, just looking for the reason.

Comment: The original library implements inner namespace `txMode {isolationLevel, TransactionMode}`. TypeScript cannot work-around JavaScript namespaces, you have to use the combination whereby you import the containing namespace, and then extract its properties. There is no other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To import independently:

```
import {txMode} from 'pg-promise';

const {TransactionMode, isolationLevel} = txMode;
```

- To import from the root interface:

```
import * as pgPromise from 'pg-promise';

const {TransactionMode, isolationLevel} = pgPromise.txMode;
```

> why I can't import the various classes and enums as I usually do?

Because [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) is a JavaScript library, with some TypeScript declarations on top of it, it is not a native TypeScript module. In fact, it was written so long ago, no TypeScript existed back then.

P.S. I'm the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

**UPDATE**

Following this, `txMode` declaration [has been updated](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/10.14.1), which now avoids the original issue.

Comment: Thank you for answering. If you don't mind me asking (I'm learning JS/TS), is there a way for a JS library to declare the TS types in such a way that they match up with the internal structure of the library? In other words, importing an object or type means I can use it "as-is". I've used many JS libraries that had TS typings and I had never encountered this issue before. What makes pg-promise different in that respect?

Comment: See the UPDATE in my answer.